# pandas dataframe - column selection

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following input dataframe:

```
PRECISE 1   RE=130  VAL=5   LENGHT=8    TYPE=DEL    AF=0.0005
PRECISE 8   RE=30   VAL=8   LENGHT=8    TYPE=INS    AF=0.05
PRECISE 3   RE=13   VAL=85  LENGHT=8    TYPE=INV    AF=0.08
PRECISE 7   RE=10   VAL=18  LENGHT=8    TYPE=DEL    AF=0.001
```

I would like to select columns if the panda.Series contains the following value `('RE=','AF=')`. I cannot select by column name as depending on the version of the tool used to generate the file, it can be variable. But the tags remains unchanged among the different versions of the tool.

Expected output :

```
RE=130  AF=0.0005
RE=30   AF=0.05
RE=13   AF=0.08
RE=10   AF=0.001
```

I tried with the following code :

`RE_cols = [col for col in df_b.columns if df_b[col].str.contains('RE=')]`

But I have the following error message that I didn't managed to resolve :

`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Any help ?

Comment: Evaluate `f_b[col].str.contains('RE=')` by itself. You'll get a Series bool values. Hence your error. You can collapse that down to a scalar with the `.any()` or `.all()`

Answer (score 0):

```
#import pandas
import pandas as pd
```

---

## Setup

Let's say you have a dataframe:

```
data = {'data1': ['A', 'B', 'Cz', 'D'], 'data2': ['az', 'za', 'c', 'd']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index',
                       columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'])
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

---

## Solution

For example, if you want to select columns containing the letter `z`:

You can do:

```
some_string_the_column_needs_to_contain_to_be_selected = 'z'
filtered_df=df[[col for col in df.columns if any(df[col].str.contains(some_string_the_column_needs_to_contain_to_be_selected))]]
```

Your `filtered_df` will be:

[image]

As expected.